# How to pass URLSearchParams in the HttpClient "get" method - Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular5, httpclient

I used **Angular 4.2** with the **Http** service and I used the get method like this where params is a URLSearchParams object:

```
this.http.get(url, {headers: this.setHeaders(), search: params})
```

I want to migrate to **Angular 5**.
http is now a **HttpClient** object like recommended by the angular team.
I got an error with the 'search' key.

Do you know how to migrate Http to HttpClient service in my case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Since Angular 4.3 you can use `HttpClient` like this :

```
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }    

   getData(){
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers  = headers.append('header-1', 'value-1');
        headers  = headers.append('header-2', 'value-2');

       let params = new HttpParams();
       params = params.append('param-1', 'value-1');
       params = params.append('param-2', 'value-2');

       this.httpClient.get("/data", {headers , params })
   }
```

`HttpParams` and `HttpHeaders` are  immutable classes so after each call of `set` or `append` methods they return a new instance that's why you should do  this : `params = params.append(...)`

Answer (score 9):

Angular 4 Way:

```
this.http.get(url, {headers: this.setHeaders(), search: params})
```

Angular 5 Way:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
let params = new HttpParams().set('paramName', paramValue);
this.http.get(url,  { params: params })
```

Multiple Params:

```
// Initialize Params Object
let Params = new HttpParams();

// Begin assigning parameters
Params = Params.append('firstParameter', firstVal);
Params = Params.append('secondParameter', secondVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following will be the changes, you need to do:

- Replace Older Http import with:

  import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
- Create HttpClient object as below:

  constructor(
      protected httpClient: HttpClient,
    ) {}

  Now there are ways to achieve search parameter namely as below:

  public get(searchParam: string): Observable {
      return this.httpClient.get(`${this.URL}/${searchParam}`);
    }

or:

```
public get(searchParam: string): Observable<object> {
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let myParams = HttpParams().set("id", searchParam);

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'get', params: myParams });

return this.http.get("this.url",options)
         .map((res: Response) => res.json())
         .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation when there were multiple parameters that needed to be passed to the api. The only thing that worked for me is when calling set() method in the same line chained together during HttpParams object intialization:

```
public get(userid: string, username: string): Observable<object> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let myParams = HttpParams().set("id", userid).set("username", username);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'get', params: 
myParams });
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpParams has two methods set(string, string) & append(string, string).

- set is clear - doc: Replaces the value for a parameter:

  ```
  let httpParams = new HttpParams();
  httpParams = httpParams.set('page', '0');
  httpParams = httpParams.set('page', '1');

  // httpParams.toString() -> 'page=1'
  ```
- appned - doc is missleading for me: Appends a new value to existing values for a parameter.

  So I would expect on that doc:

  ```
  let httpParams = new HttpParams();
  httpParams = httpParams.add('page', '0');
  httpParams = httpParams.add('page', '1');

  // httpParams.toString() -> 'page=1,2'
  ```

  But actual (angular 11.2.14) behavior is:

  ```
  let httpParams = new HttpParams();
  httpParams = httpParams.add('page', '0');
  httpParams = httpParams.add('page', '1');

  // httpParams.toString() -> 'page=1&page=2'
  ```

But still I need to to have different variants:

1. `page=0&size=10` - solvable by `httpParams` `set` method
2. `sort=id,asc&sort=statusId,desc` - solvable by `httpParams` `add` method
3. `search=id>100,id<500,statusId:3` - needs to be solved manually