# How to set default query params for Route in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular-routing, ngrx-router-store

In our Angular-7-Application, we use @ngrx and @ngrx/router-store to get the query params into the state.

A few components of the application are paginated lists. We have every list as a component and the Pagination-Component included in every list.

The current page is stored in the URL as a query Parameter: `user/:userId/agent?page=0` and the PaginationComponent gets the current page from `state.router.state.queryParams.page`. However, if a user accesses the URL `user/:userId/agent`, `queryParams.page` returns undefined.

We could solve this by using `state.router.state.queryParams.page || 0` in every component but I wonder, if there is an easier way - **can a Route without query params be redirect to a Route with query params**?

I tried using the most obvious redirect:

```
{ path: 'user/:userId/agent', redirectTo: '/user/:userId/agent?page=0', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'user/:userId/agent?page=0', component: AgentListComponent },
```

but I get `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/max/agent'`.

The only feature request I found was [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9921) where the error above appears.

Comment: I feel this is a broad question, because there are many ways. You could use a guard that redirects, the component could do it, etc. etc. But, Angular can  not match routes with query parameters. That's not a supported feature, and I don't think it ever will be.

Comment: To be honest, adding `|| 0` is *truly* the least effort and easiest to maintain. I think you're over thinking the issue, and shorter URLs are easier to read URLs.

Comment: Adding `|| 0` to every component in which it is used is the least effort, but it contradicts the DRY-principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question specifically:

> can a Route without query params be redirect to a Route with query params?

I don't think this can work because the ? in a query is a separator, which is not part of a URL's query string.

**Alternative 1** - since you are using ngrx, one way to do it is to use the custom serializer. [The docs from the ngrx.io site](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/configuration#custom-router-state-serializer) show an example of returning the params with serialization. This is where you can add logic to add a default to the params if it doesn't exist. I'll disclaim this may be less ideal because it'll fire on each route, but it can make your routes simpler.

```
import { Params, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterStateSerializer } from '@ngrx/router-store';

export interface RouterStateUrl {
  url: string;
  params: Params;
  queryParams: Params;
}

export class CustomSerializer implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateUrl> {
  serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl {
    let route = routerState.root;

    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route.firstChild;
    }

    const {
      url,
      root: { queryParams },
    } = routerState;
    const { params } = route;

    // Add here
    if (<insert url logic> && queryParams.page === undefined) {
        queryParams.page = 0;
    }

    // Only return an object including the URL, params and query params
    // instead of the entire snapshot
    return { url, params, queryParams };
  }
}
```

**Alternative 2** - You can wrap the HttpClient or more preferably, create a generic page list method that checks for this and adds it to the request if there is no page. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551842/10747134) shows an example of how to achieve adding params.

**Alternative 3** - You can use the page as a part of the path and do work arounds/changes as needed to generate your requests.

```
{ path: 'user/:userId/agent', redirectTo: '/user/:userId/agent/0', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'user/:userId/agent/:page', component: AgentListComponent },
```

Comment: I'm already using the serializer you described and did not think about putting it there. Thanks!

Comment: I have to add that `queryParams.page = 0` does not work because of `preventExtensions` is true. I solved it by using a new Object: `Object.assign({}, { page = 0 }, queryParams);`

Comment: When will the coed snippet-1 will get trigerred?

Answer (score 1):

> In our Angular-7-Application, we use @ngrx and @ngrx/router-store to get the query params into the state.

To have query params and state synchronized you need an effect that captures any action that results in a page change in your application. Inside the event, you'll have something like:

```
@Effect({dispatch:false})
setRouteParams = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<ActionCausingPageChange>("action name"),
    tap( action =>{

        let a = { page: action.payload.page };
        // or in case it's not part of action payload, get it from store
        this.router.navigate(
            [], {
                relativeTo: this.route,
                queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
                queryParams: a
            });
        }
    )
);
```

Then have a meta reducer to update state from query params on page reload:

```
export function initStateFromQueryParams(
    reducer: ActionReducer<AppState>
): ActionReducer<AppState> {
    return function(state, action) {
        const newState = reducer(state, action);
        if ([INIT.toString(), UPDATE.toString()].includes(action.type)) {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            return { ...newState, page: urlParams.get("page") };
        }
        return newState;
    };
}
```

This way you always know if page number changes it's gonna be reflected in url consequently. So even if you go to a new route(component) after that route gets its initial data the effect will trigger which updates query params.

You may want to checkout out this phenomenal [article](https://blog.nrwl.io/managing-state-in-angular-applications-22b75ef5625f) about state management in angular apps

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article. The following made me wonder whether the navigation should take place inside the effect or outside: "Since the user can always interact with the URL directly, we should treat the router as the source of truth and the initiator of actions."

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked on the root path:

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/foo?bar=baz',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

However when trying the same with a named param (like your `:userId`) it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for this functionality is in the routing module, create a route to a component:

```
{
    path: 'route-to-component-that-redirects-here',
    component: MyRedirectComponent
}
```

Then in the component, you can navigate with the queryParms set to what you want back to the route you want:

```
// MyRedirectComponent

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/route-i-want-here'], { queryParams: { p: 'value' } });
}
```

Comment: This would lead to two routing actions, which I want to avoid.